# Swift Target not fireing when called from another class

Tags: swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to create a image swift class/file and then add it to the view in another class...it has gestures attached to it programmatically using addTarget

```
class GestureCreate: UIImageView,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

init(){
    let imageName = "hairoverlay"
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName)

    super.init(image: image)


    self.overlayImage = UIImageView(image: image!)

    self.overlayImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200)
    self.overlayImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.overlayImage.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    // view.addSubview(overlayImage)



    self.pinchGesture.delegate = self





    self.pinchGesture.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GestureCreate.pinchAction(_:)))


    self.overlayImage.addGestureRecognizer(self.pinchGesture)

}
```

and then in the view controller I have

```
        var test = GestureCreate()
       self.view.addSubview(test.overlayImage)
```

Its funny because the image appears on the view but the actions I tryed adding to it doesnt work... anyone know whats up?

Comment: pretty sure you just need: #selector(pinchAction)

Comment: self.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture) im pretty sure was the fix